# Type Mismatch using Selenium in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, type-mismatch

```
Sub

 Dim ChBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver

 Set ChBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

 Dim PeerComparisonTable As Selenium.WebElement
 Dim PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow As Selenium.TableRow
```

**[Chrome]**

**URL -** https://www.screener.in/company/DIVISLAB/consolidated/

**Question :**  How to reference the **header row** from the **PeerComparision table?**

**header row** - [How to Reference this row ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h76Ei.jpg)

**Error : Type Mismatch**

```
 Set PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow = ChBrowser.FindElementsByTag("table")(1).FindElementsByTag("tr")(1)
```

**[Internet Explorer] -**  There was **'Rows'** method available. What is the **workaround** for **Chrome?**

```
 Set PeerComparisonTable = IE.getElementsByTagName("table")(1)

 Set PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow = PeerComparisonTable.Rows(index)

End Sub
```

Comment: Find the element by xPath method: /html/body/main/section[3]/div[1]

Comment: `Dim a As WebElement: Set a = ChBrowser.FindElementByCss("table row")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow object, from 'TableRow' to 'WebElement', and use xPath to find that:

(note that the web address is different of that you have posted)

```
Sub fnTestChrome()
    Dim ChBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim PeerComparisonTable As Selenium.WebElement
    Dim PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow As Selenium.WebElement
        
    Set ChBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

    ChBrowser.Start "chrome"
    DoEvents
    ChBrowser.Get "https://www.screener.in/company/DIVISLAB/consolidated/#peers"
    DoEvents
    Set PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow = ChBrowser.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/main/section[3]/div[1]")
    
    MsgBox PeerComparisonTableHeaderRow.Text
    
End Sub
```